# Using FromBody to send variable to web API method - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a WebApi method that call a method in repository. Repository method calls a stored procedure and send 4 input and the output is a string. I have problem in web api how to send the input variable to it and what the URI is looks like.

This is the repository method:

public async Task AddUserAsync(AddUser user)
   { 
       return await this.Context.AddUserAsync(user);
   }

This is Web API method : I have to use `[FromBody]` how I can use it how to send input variable to this method? Can I test it with PostMan?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddUser/{user}")]
public async Task<string> AddUser([FromBody]AddUser user)
{
    return  Exception = await Repository.AddUserAsync(user);
}
```

and this is User object:

```
[DataContract]
public class AddUser
{      
    [DataMember]
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Salt { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RemoteRefNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I wonder how the User object from API to Repository? Also what would be the URI I tried this but the User is Null when I debug:

```
http://localhost:59509/Adduser/user?UserEmailAddress=test@yahoo.com&PasswordHash=abc&Salt=123&RemoteRefNumber=foo
```

Comment: What is the type of client side do you use to request your server?

Answer (score 0):

if you post, the data should be part of the request body with key value pairs. Based on your URL, it seems like your using a GET.

```
[HttpPost, Route(Name = "create:account"), Authorize(Roles = Account.Editor)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(Account acc)


$.ajax(
    url: "",
    type: "post",
    dataType:"json",
    data: { 
        userEmailAddress  : "test@test.com"
    }
)
```

Comment: I am using post it now, but when I post the user is empty.

Comment: can you use monitor the HTTP messages and see what's being posted. Use fiddler or firebug and monitor the network traffic.

Comment: in webapi, complex objects are pulled from the body. so no need for FromBody. You need FromUri attribute, if your GET operation takes a complex object.

Comment: how I can send it with using [FromBody] not in URI.

Comment: WebApi will do it for you. It's part of it's algorithm for parameter binding.

Comment: I've updated my code. You can see that my POST doesn't use FromBody.

Comment: also based on your code, it seems like you're using form based authentication, you might as well use asp.net identity and save some time.

Comment: but they told me I have to use [FromBody]

Comment: which version of asp.net are you using? asp.net 4 or 5? I think in asp.net 5 using .net core, you might have to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110665/discussion-between-alma-and-kmc).

Answer (score 0):

You've set this up as a GET request, whereby the parameters are usually injected as URL query string parameters.

Posts work differently. You submit a form which has a collection of inputs and values and this is automatically sent in the Request Body.

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddUser")]
public async Task<string> AddUser(AddUser user)
{
    return  Exception = await Repository.AddUserAsync(user);
}
```

On the client side you just need to set your form action to the controller action URL and use the Post type.

Also, it is better to base your forms/views on a ViewModel and accept this on your controller action. You then map/convert it to the data model entity.